# How to start spring-boot app without depending on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Question [How to start spring-boot app without depending on Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850585/how-to-start-spring-boot-app-without-depending-on-database) solves how to start a spring-boot app when mysql is down.

Is it possible to do the same with mongoDB?

Couldn't find any property in [Spring boot application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) that would support it.

Spring-boot config

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/measurements-db
```

I get the following stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'diseaseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=docker.me:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=docker.me:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=docker.me:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=docker.me:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:75) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:162) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:133) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:125) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:51) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:179) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:66) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:92) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=docker.me:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:664) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$500(DBTCPConnector.java:40) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:513) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:456) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:415) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.createIndex(DBCollectionImpl.java:378) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:597) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:142) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you have the exact same exception when you're trying with MongoDB ?

Comment: I don't get the same exception as he got with mysql. Updated question with the stack trace.

Comment: Based on @jsorah's answer I found this usefull [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003179/please-use-mongomappingcontextsetautoindexcreationboolean-or-override-mong/60017959#60017959) thah did the trick

Comment: Based on @jsorah's answer I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003179/please-use-mongomappingcontextsetautoindexcreationboolean-or-override-mong/60017959#60017959) very usefull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *3* years later... but this is now possible.

The problem is that auto index creation is enabled. With Spring Boot 2.2 this is now possible to disable and defer any necessary index creation to an ApplicationReadyEvent listener on startup.

The specific property you need to change is `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation` and set 
that to false (which will be the default value in a future version).

Below is a sample of the ApplicationReadyEvent listener that can (and should!) take its place.

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {
    IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(DomainType.class);
    IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);
    resolver.resolveIndexFor(DomainType.class).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
}
```