# Execute task async in DB on Spring startup

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to make my spring boot application start without connection to the db. The approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850585/how-to-start-spring-boot-app-without-depending-on-database) seems to be very promising, however, my application executes a `CommandLineRunner` which does some db maintainance (verifying that all indices are in place etc.) on startup. In order to avoid getting timeouts there, I tried to run the `CommandLineRunner` method asynchronously (using Spring's `@Async`), trying to get a db connection until it succeeds, but I'm still getting timeout exceptions. I assume that async execution of the `CommandLineRunner` method doesn't work.

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor to make the whatever functionality is within the `CommandLineRunner` be scheduled with a `TaskScheduler`, and schedule it enough time in the future to avoid the timeouts. On failure you could gracefully shutdown the spring boot application if the maintenance isn't ran as expected.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler

> The simplest method is the one named 'schedule' that takes a Runnable and Date only. **That will cause the task to run once after the specified time**. All of the other methods are capable of scheduling tasks to run repeatedly. The fixed-rate and fixed-delay methods are for simple, periodic execution, but the method that accepts a Trigger is much more flexible.