# Start spring application without database running

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

My application requires connecting to multiple databases like Postgres, elastic-search. I want my application to run even though my Postgres db is not up, but spring bean initialization fails saying

`Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Connection to localhost:5432 refused.`.

I am using jdbcTemplate to connect to Postgres db. Can someone suggest me how to do it in spring?

The question is similar to [How to start spring-boot app without depending on Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850585/how-to-start-spring-boot-app-without-depending-on-database) but that question involves mysql and I am using postgresql. The solution to that question doesn't work in my case.

Comment: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})` using these exclude you can make the app start without the Database.

Comment: Not tested, but setting initializationFailTimeout to a negative value should do the trick. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#infrequently-used

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850585/how-to-start-spring-boot-app-without-depending-on-database ?